# How to set a variable counter based on a non specific cell in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I basically want to set a macro that, when run, will select a range of data to create a chart. The amount of columns in the data is set at 2, but the amount of rows will change as more data is added. I was thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
Sheets("Risk ranking").Range("C2:D" & counter & ").select
```

And then using that selection to create the graph (the syntax may be off for that selection... still not too good at know where to place  " and & in this kind of scenario... please provide a fix to that as well if it is wrong). The thing is, I need the counter to be an integer equaling the difference between the second row and one less than the first empty ("") cell when going down the rows. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With Sheets("Risk ranking")
   .Range("C2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row).Select
End With
```

This will always size your range to go to the farthest down non-empty row in column "C".

To set chart range:

```
With Sheets("Risk ranking")
   Charts(1).SetSourceData Source:= .Range("C2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row)
End With
```

Comment: Not what I had initially thought to do, but certainly much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: How do I make this range select though, since its within a "with"?

Comment: See my edit. I highly recommend you do not select it though. If you are trying to use this as a chart range, directly set the chart range to the range desired instead of selecting it for any purpose. I can help in doing that as well if you post more code.

Comment: How would you do that, even generally? Could you just give me a general example, because it would be really helpful?

Comment: See edit. Also, if this did in fact answer your question, please mark my answer as accepted.